# JavaScript - Output characters randomly

Tags: javascript, random, character, output

Not sure how to go about this but I need to output a set of characters x, y and z. The output is 3 characters long and consists of x,y and z. However the characters are as likely as each other. Basically output characters (from a set, in this case x,y and z) randomly. Example outputs - xyy, zzz, yyz etc. I'm guessing I need a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var chars = ['x','y','z'];
function show_chars(arr){
    var l = arr.length;
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*l)] 
       + arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*l)] 
       + arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*l)]
}
console.log(show_chars(chars));
```

Comment: @RobG, "Example outputs - xyy, zzz, yyz etc." That's taken from the question.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VNh7n/1/**

```
function randomXYZ() {
    return 'xxx'.replace(/x/g, function () {
        return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 120);
    });
}

console.log(randomXYZ());
```

Comment: `(122 - 120 + 1)` is a long–winded way of writing `3`.

Comment: @RobG, Yeah I wanted it to be obvious so that the OP understands the formula but I forgot to explain it anyway =P I guess i'll just put 3, it's pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

For random combinations where each character only appears once:

```
function shuffleChars(s) {
  s = s.split('');
  var i = s.length;
  var result = [];
  while (i) {
    result.push(s.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (i--)),1));
  }
  return result;
}
```

For random combinations where a character may appear any number of times up to the length of the string:

```
function randomChars(s) {
  s = s.split('');
  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length, result=[]; i<iLen; i++) {
    result[i] = s[Math.random() * iLen | 0];
  }
  return result;
}

randomChars('xyz');
```

Both of the above can take strings of any length.